# How to force that sources do not depend on a third party library

Tags: gradle

In my build.gradle I would like to prevent that `src/main/java/**.java` depend on a specific third party library (let's say e.g. guava).

So I thought to *intercept* the `classes` task and make the build fail, if any of the dependencies (direct or transitive) is the unwanted library.

```
classes {
    doLast {
        // PROBLEM: does not consider transitive dependencies
        configurations.compile.allDependencies.findAll { dep ->
            // println dep
            if (dep.group == 'com.google.guava')
                throw new GradleException("must not depend on guava: " + dep)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the build fail, even if there is a transitive dependency on the unwanted library? Can the output be made helpful to discover *how* it is a transitive dependency (dependency chain)?

Comment: Why don't you just exclude guava from your compile dependencies? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies

Comment: I just want to *guarantee* that all dependencies, that transitively depend on guava, exclude it. If tomorrow a fellow adds a new dependency that buys in guava transitively, the build shall fail.